# How best to sanitize input in Java webapp

Tags: java, security, validation

We use jsp, servlets, beans with mysql database. We don't want to restrict the characters entered by users on form fields. So how do I sanitize the input and how to make sure the output is not changed for malicious activities. Is there way while sending the output I could check if extra code has been sent. Like suppose there is search input field -- the user gives something like `<script>alert("I am here")</script>`. Is there anway I could know this is a html tag. If the user appends an extra parameter to a link field, is there like a before and after check I could do for the document to realize there has been a extra link field.

Comment: Please consider renaming your questions to soemthing like "How best to sanitize input in Java" - your question title won't help those looking for similar answers in future...

Comment: Whoa, when you go to retag the question, it executes the javascript in the question! Bad stackoverflow, bad!

Answer (score 16):

Give [`jsoup`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) a go to help you out with this. Whatever you do, don't try to hack this up using regex or something, because then you'll have 2 problems. :-)

With `jsoup`, all you need is a short snippet of code:

```
String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
```

You can add tags and attributes to `Whitelist` fairly easily, though I found it doesn't support namespace tags.

Comment: Note that `Whitelist` has been deprecated (will be removed in 1.15.1) in favor of `Safelist`

Answer (score 13):

You really should allow users to input as little HTML and/or javascript as possible. One good solution to validating and sanitizing this stuff is to use a ready-made library like [OWASP AntiSamy](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project).

Also, take a look at [OWASP Enterprise Security API](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API) for a collection of security methods that a developer needs to build a secure web application.

Comment: Dec, 2021:  [AntiSamy Project](https://owasp.org/www-project-antisamy/)

Answer (score 8):

You should always do basic HTML-escaping of data taken from sources like user input or the database that might contain invalid characters. The `<c:out>` JSP tag does this, for example. That way if the user enters `"<script> ..."` in a field and you are printing it back again, it will be printed to the HTML as `"&lt;script&gt; ..."`.