# How to stop someone uploading a script in textarea?

Tags: html, textarea, validation

I have a situation where users can submit feedback through a textarea on a HTML page or JSP. This works fine and the text ends up in the database.

But, can anyone suggest any safeguards which could prevent somebody trying to submit  malicious scripts which could possibly affect the page's behaviour?

I am aware of parsing the text entered and converting any < to '&LT'; and > to '&GT'; But is there anything more I could do to validate the entered text?

Thanks

Mr Morgan

Comment: this was already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761588/how-best-to-sanitize-input-in-java-webapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:
[Recommended method for escaping HTML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java)

See Apache StringEscapeUtils

escapeJavaScript
and
escapeHtml